# Is there a way of handling max file size in ng-file-upload when the inputs are divs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

Given the following code:

```
<form ng-app="fileUpload"  name="form">
  <div ngf-select ng-model="fileFront" name="fileFront" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="2MB">
     <span>Click hereto upload photo</span>
  </div>
  <i ng-show="form.fileFront.$error.maxSize">File too large</i>
</form>
```

I cannot make the bullet tag to be displayed, I think the problem is related to the fact that form does not contains the fileFront.

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: `fileFront` is a model can you not just bind the bullet's ng-show to the variable in the controller? That *should* make it trigger when the value changes.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickBarr but I need to show the bullet when the maxSize has been exceeded which is something that the library ng-file-upload provides me on that "form.fileFront.$error.maxSize" model